# MongoDB aggregation framework support non-aggregation operations?

Tags: mongodb

I have following query using MongoDB aggregation,

```
db.users.aggregate({$project: {"name":1}})
```

The result is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d19a17a368e9d89b84269b2"), "name" : "sharon" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d19a186368e9d89b84269b5"), "name" : "paul" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d19a1a7368e9d89b84269b8"), "name" : "paul" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d19a1bb368e9d89b84269bb"), "name" : "sharon" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d19a1ca368e9d89b84269be"), "name" : "paul" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d19a1cf368e9d89b84269c1"), "name" : "paul" }
```

This is effectively equivalent to

```
db.users.find({"name":1})
```

So, I am confused and surprised that `aggregate` support non-aggregation operations,

I have thought that `aggregate` is similar to `SQL group by`, but the above query is impossible in SQL

Comment: No the above aggregation is equivalent to `db.users.find({ }, {"name":1})`. And answer to your question:--> limiting the fields is also the part of an aggregation and that is what `$project` does here. `.find` just provides the relaxation by providing projection in the second parameter of its function.

Comment: Thanks @Ashh, so is there performance difference  between  `aggregate/project` and  `find`, I think `find` should be faster

Comment: Well, [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) *is* an aggregation pipeline operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have thought that `aggregate` is similar to `SQL group by`, but the above query is impossible in SQL

It is not at all. The aggregation framework defines a number of possible *stages* that you can put your data through, of which [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) is one. Each stage modifies the result set in some way. You need to think of each stage as *set of documents goes in, different set of documents comes out*. [Grouping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is one of the possible things you can do in an aggregation stage, but there are [many more possible transformations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: Looks the name of `aggregate` is kind of misleading, this method is more like a transformation pipeline, mainly used for aggregation.

Comment: Depends on how you define the word "aggregate". Given operations like `$lookup`, there are forms of "aggregation" that don't mean "group". But yes, it's really a transformation pipeline.

Comment: I liked the name "Aggregation Pipeline" better (that's what it was called initially).

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing to a [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) in the aggregation framework is the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator.

The `Aggregation Framework` is resorted to, to ease the query of a big number of entries and generate a low number of results that hold value to you.

While the find can be used to manipulate results, this will involve the performance of the underlying programming language you are using to perform the find and further manipulation.

Where as, in the aggregation framework only the mongoengine determines the performance and might thus make things easier for you.